# What are the Module specific heaps reported by sos.eeheap?

Tags: clr, windbg, sos

When I run `!eeheap -loader` SOS command in WinDbg against a memory dump of any .NET process, it outputs two strange groups of of heaps after the domains and JIT code heap.

Here is the output:

```
0:000> !eeheap -loader
Loader Heap:
--------------------------------------
...........
--------------------------------------
Module Thunk heaps:
Module 000007fecb601000: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 000007fee8bc1000: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
...........
Total size:              Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Module Lookup Table heaps:
Module 000007fecb601000: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
Module 000007fee8bc1000: Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
...........
Total size:              Size: 0x0 (0) bytes.
--------------------------------------
Total LoaderHeap size:   Size: 0xd55000 (13979648) bytes total, 0xb0000 (720896) bytes wasted.
=======================================
```

What are the "Module Thunk heaps" and "Module Lookup Table heaps"? And why are they always zero size?
The only thing I know is that the both of these heaps contain references to every loaded module.